# Android:Contacts Phone.TYPE

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I need a little help with this.. I need to take only the numbers of type Mobile in this contacts list.

with this code I extract ALL the numbers, Instead I need to take only mobile type..and show them in the list.
help me, and thanks in advance!

code:

```
void ReadContacts(String sort) {
        final Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
         final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Contacts._ID,
                 Phone.NUMBER,
                 Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                 Phone.TYPE
         };
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        final String sortOrder = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        m_curContacts = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        String[] fields = new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
        m_slvAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_mio,m_curContacts,fields, 
                new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2});           

        m_slvAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() { 
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "runQuery constraint:"+constraint);
                String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'" +
                    " AND "+ Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"+constraint+"%'";
                String[] selectionArgs = null;//new String[]{"'1'"};//, };
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                return cur;
            }

        });
```

ps: the Phone.TYPE  mobile is int 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set Selection and selectionArg to following:

```
selection="ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP =? and Phone.TYPE=?";
selectionArgs=new String[]{"1", "2"};
```